# Matlab norm function adds an extra element to a vector?

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

I have a cell array (data) containing 3 matrices, each with 18 columns and 108021, 108022 and 108021 rows respectively. I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between columns 13, 14 and 15, 16 for each matrix and I am using the following code:

```
for m = 1:length(data)
 for i = 1:length(data{m})
  distance(i) = norm(data{m}(i,13:14)-data{m}(i,15:16));
 end
end
```

It works except for the last matrix (when m=3) to which it adds an extra element. So that now distance is a cell array with 3 vectors of sizes 108021, 108022 and 108022...

Anyone knows whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Auesro

Comment: Don't you want something like `distance{m}(i) = norm(...`. Now the vector `distance` is overwritten with each outer loop iteration, and since the middle loop makes the vector 108022 elements, it will keep this last element untouched in the last iteration, i.e. when `m=3`.

Comment: Thanks for that! That was actually the problem. However, I cannot directly make ``distance´´ a cell array because I apply ```movmean´´´ to each distance vector and it requires a numeric input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could preallocate the `distance` variable to a matrix and store the values there.

```
distance = zeros(length(data),max(cellfun('size',data,1)));
for m = 1:length(data)
 for i = 1:length(data{m})
  distance(m,i) = norm(data{m}(i,13:14)-data{m}(i,15:16));
 end
end
```

or if `distance` had to be a cell array

```
for m = 1:length(data)
 for i = 1:length(data{m})
  d{m}(i) = norm(data{m}(i,13:14)-data{m}(i,15:16));
 end
end
```

Comment: I tried the second option and it works. However, it is a bit more complicated than that because after creating distance I apply a movmean that requires a numerical input, not a cell input...

Comment: @AugustoEscalante The answer covers the scenario you mentioned in the question. However, Can the distances be negative? If no, then you might try the first option and set the elements not used to a negative value for example. If yes, you could set it to a unique value (pi for example). Then you know which ones to exclude.

Comment: The answer was perfect and it works. I will try as suggested.